# Getting Unbound local Error: local variable 'x' referenced below assignment

Tags: python

I have a python flask app that is receiving webhook from another application. When it receives the webhook, it responds back by carry out a task (looking up someone's availability) and responding back to the web application with a response. I am getting an unbound local error local variable 'response' referenced below assignment when sending a response back. It looks like calling response at that level is causing issues. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response
import logging
import json
import random
import os
import importlib
import win32com.client
import pywintypes
import datetime
import pythoncom
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import string

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    logger.info("Incoming request: %s", req)
    intent = get_intent_from_req(req)
    logger.info('Detected intent %s', intent)

    if intent == "Check Schedule Next":
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        emailparam = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters').get('email')
        datetime1 = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters').get('date-time').get("date_time")
        datetime2=datetime1.replace('T',' ')
        datetime3=datetime2.replace("-04:00", "")
        print(datetime3)
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        class MeetingRoom:
            def __init__(self, inputDate, duration, locationMail):
                self.inputDate = inputDate
                self.oOutlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
                self.bookings = self.oOutlook.CreateItem(1)
                self.bookings.Start = inputDate
                self.bookings.Duration = duration
                self.bookings.Subject = 'Follow Up Meeting'
                self.bookings.MeetingStatus = 1
                self.roomRecipient = self.bookings.Recipients.Add(locationMail)

            def checkRoomAvailability(self):
               bookingDateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.inputDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                self.roomRecipient.resolve
                myDate = bookingDateTime.date()
                pywintypeDate = pywintypes.Time(myDate)
                availabilityInfo = self.roomRecipient.FreeBusy(pywintypeDate, self.bookings.Duration, True)
                timeAvailability = []
                newTime = pywintypeDate
                # print(newTime)
                currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
                for isAvailable in availabilityInfo:
                    # print(newTime, " :: ", isAvailable)
                    if isAvailable == "0" and newTime > currentTime:
                        timeAvailability.append(newTime)
                    newTime = newTime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=self.bookings.Duration)

                # print(availabilityInfo)
                # for value in timeAvailability:
                #     print(value)
                try:
                    index = timeAvailability.index(bookingDateTime)
                    print(emailparam, "is available")
                    response = {
                    'fulfillmentText': emailparam
                    }
                    # self.bookings.Save()
                    # self.bookings.Send()

                except ValueError:
                    for timestamp in timeAvailability:
                        if bookingDateTime <= timestamp:
                            break
                print("I dont see availability for", emailparam, "at", bookingDateTime, " but next available time is ", timestamp)
                x = ("I dont see availability for", emailparam, "at", bookingDateTime, " but next available time is ", timestamp)
                response = {
                    'fulfillmentText': x
                }
                # def bookMeetingRoom():

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            meetingRoomObj = MeetingRoom(datetime3, 15, emailparam)
            meetingRoomObj.checkRoomAvailability()
        #response = {
        #    'fulfillmentText': emailparam
        #}

    res = create_response(response)
    return res

def get_intent_from_req(req):
    try:
        intent_name = req['queryResult']['intent']['displayName']
    except KeyError:
        return None

    return intent_name

def get__from_req(req):
    try:
        intent_name = req['queryResult']['intent']['displayName']
    except KeyError:
        return None

    return intent_name


def create_response(response):
    res = json.dumps(response, indent=4)

    logger.info(res)

    r = make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LISTEN = ('0.0.0.0',8080)
    http_server = WSGIServer( LISTEN, app )
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Include the entire error message, and reduce your code the minimum needed to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This line references `response` before it's initialized:

```
res = create_response(response)
```

Perhaps make sure all code paths initialize the `response` varaiable?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Add res = create_response(response) under if __name__="__main__":?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

It seems you've created your `response` object in the wrong scope, remove it from the function `checkRoomAvailability`.

Inside the function `checkRoomAvailability` after you've created the response object, return it like so

```
response = {
                'fulfillmentText': x
            }
return response #ADD THIS LINE
```

Remove these lines

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        meetingRoomObj = MeetingRoom(datetime3, 15, emailparam)
        meetingRoomObj.checkRoomAvailability()
```

Then add back the object creation and call right before you create your response like so

```
meetingRoomObj = MeetingRoom(datetime3, 15, emailparam)
response = meetingRoomObj.checkRoomAvailability()
res = create_response(response)
return res
```

**Suggestion**

You are lacking some fundamental understanding about how python or scope works so I suggest taking a read friend 
https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: Tried out the solution, looks like I'm still getting local variable error..

Comment: doubel check your indentation and if you're still having issues, post a stacktrace